# Retrieving file from bytea in PostgreSQL using java

Tags: java, postgresql, postgresql-9.1, binarystream, bytea

Hi I'm using the below code to retrieve the file from the postgresql bytea using java,
 but inside the file I'm getting numbers like 314530413142313141

```
File file = new File("c:/test.doc");
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM test_bytea where id=" + 1);
        if (rs != null) {
            while (rs.next()) {

                byte[] fileBytes = new byte[1024];
                InputStream is = rs.getBinaryStream("type_file");
                while (is.read(fileBytes) > 0) {
                    fos.write(fileBytes);
                }

                // use the stream in some way here
            }
            rs.close();
        }
```

Please let me know what goes wrong in my code?

Comment: Are you **absolutely** sure the `type_file` is of type `bytea`? The behaviour you describe sounds like the column is defined as `oid`

Comment: yes 100% im sure the type_file is the cloumn name of the bytea datatype

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to download bytea column as file using Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33107318/how-to-download-bytea-column-as-file-using-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data is escaped ( starts with \x and then is hexadecimal two chars for each byte) this is what comes out of a bytea field.  you need to unescape it before storing it in the file.

Comment: do you have any idea, that how to implement this?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing it manually, you can use `Spring`:

```
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM test_bytea where id=" + 1);
if (rs != null) {
    LobHandler lobHandler = new DefaultLobHandler();
    byte[] myFile = lobHandler.getBlobAsBytes(rs, "type_file"));
    //....
```

Comment: Q: "How do I do this in Javascript?" A: "Not sure, but here is how you do it using jQuery". There's no `spring` tag in that question.

Comment: @oligofren So what? It's another way, which works. Don't go answer-nazi for nothing, dude ;) Cheers